# How to find the number of solution of $x^n=1$ in the group $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups

Suppose that $S_n$, the symmetric group of order $n!$ is given and for given $m\in \mathbb N$ fixed, we are to find the number of solutions to $\theta^m=e, \theta\in S_n$.

Can someone tell me or give some idea how to proceed ? what condition shall I impose on $n, m$ ? etc

Comment: You need every cycle length to be a divisor of $n$. (or $m$, the question is unclear)

Answer (score 0):

Some particular cases can be helpful: for $m = 2,$ we can give a general formula for number of solutions $s(n)$ provided [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/W.-Feit%2C-Characters-of-Finite-Groups.-VIII-%2B-186-S.-Hasse/58fd29ddfe66e755fdffffd3af27f584e290fe6c):

$$s(n) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \dfrac{n!}{2^k k! (n - 2k)!}.$$

Moreover, some information about existence of solutions for the mentioned equation can be found [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2322839?searchUri=/action/doBasicSearch?Query=The%2bmaximum%2border%2bof%2ban%2belement%2bof%2ba%2bfinite%2bsymmetric%2bgroup&acc=off&wc=on&fc=off&Search=yes&searchText=The&searchText=maximum&searchText=order&searchText=of&searchText=an&searchText=element&searchText=of&searchText=a&searchText=finite&searchText=symmetric&searchText=group&uid=364965821&uid=2134&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3&uid=60&sid=21103196778387). For example, by using Corollary 1 in section 2, we conclude that if $\prod\limits_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i}$ is the prime factorization of $m,$ then $\theta^m = e$ has at least one solution in $S_n$ if and only if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i} \le m.$